# Ruby Upgrade from 2.7.7 to 3.0.0 Breaks Active Admin and Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, activeadmin, dalli

I think this has something to do with the gem I'm using for memcache (dalli) but search results on this are scarce.

Rails 7.0.4
Ruby 3.0.0
Dalli 2.7.6
Devise 4.8.1

My site works (dalli is used for user sessions) but active admin throws the following error when I attempt to log in:

```
ArgumentError (wrong number of arguments (given 2, expected 1)):
  
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:147:in `delete_entry'
dalli (2.7.10) lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:167:in `block in delete'
dalli (2.7.10) lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:389:in `block in instrument_with_log'
dalli (2.7.10) lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:398:in `block in instrument'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/notifications.rb:208:in `instrument'
dalli (2.7.10) lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:397:in `instrument'
dalli (2.7.10) lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:389:in `instrument_with_log'
dalli (2.7.10) lib/active_support/cache/dalli_store.rb:166:in `delete'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/session/cache_store.rb:43:in `delete_session'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:378:in `commit_session'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:268:in `context'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/session/abstract/id.rb:260:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/cookies.rb:696:in `call'
activerecord (7.0.4) lib/active_record/migration.rb:603:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:99:in `run_callbacks'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:26:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/actionable_exceptions.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:28:in `call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:132:in `call_app'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:28:in `block in call'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `catch'
web-console (4.2.1) lib/web_console/middleware.rb:17:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:26:in `call'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:40:in `call_app'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `block in call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `block in tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:37:in `tagged'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:99:in `tagged'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:25:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:93:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:26:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/method_override.rb:24:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/runtime.rb:22:in `call'
activesupport (7.0.4) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache_middleware.rb:29:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/executor.rb:14:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/deflater.rb:44:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:23:in `call'
rack (2.2.8) lib/rack/sendfile.rb:110:in `call'
actionpack (7.0.4) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/host_authorization.rb:137:in `call'
railties (7.0.4) lib/rails/engine.rb:530:in `call'
puma (5.6.7) lib/puma/configuration.rb:252:in `call'
puma (5.6.7) lib/puma/request.rb:77:in `block in handle_request'
puma (5.6.7) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:340:in `with_force_shutdown'
puma (5.6.7) lib/puma/request.rb:76:in `handle_request'
puma (5.6.7) lib/puma/server.rb:443:in `process_client'
puma (5.6.7) lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:147:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Does anyone have an idea of what the issue could be?

Comment: https://www.ruby-lang.org/en/news/2019/12/12/separation-of-positional-and-keyword-arguments-in-ruby-3-0/